# Separar un campo en dos columnas en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, substring

Tengo una tabla donde en un campo tengo un string de la siguiente manera:

'frase1,01frase2'

y lo quiero separar de la siguiente manera :
|frase1|frase2|

no me interesa el 01 ni la coma , estaba leyendo sobre el substring pero no me queda muy claro de que manera separarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo muy claro si quieres obtener esta solución:

```
frase1  frase2
```

Obtenida con

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(frases,',01',1),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(frases,',01',-1)
  FROM debek;
```

O ésta:

```
|frase1|frase2|
```

Que se obtiene con

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('|',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(frases,',01',1),'|',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(frases,',01',-1),'|'
  )
  FROM debek;
```

A partir de estos datos:

```
CREATE TABLE debek(
  frases varchar(127)
  );

INSERT INTO debek (frases)
  VALUES ('frase1,01frase2');
```

Espero que te resulte útil cualquiera de ellas.

Comment: era la priemer solucion los '|'  eran para simular que es una tabla

Comment: Genial, me alegra que te haya servido. Recuerda dar ok a la respuesta... :)